# Java: Why is my obscenity filter replacing all last words that end in 'a' in my chat sessions?

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java and I created obscenity filter that works well except if we have a letter that ends in a it will be replaced.

eg. "I want a banana" --> "I want a bananbleep"

HOWEVER...
If you add punctuation after the 'a' it will show up correctly.

eg. "Would you like a banana?"  --> "Would you like a banana?"

Here is what I did:

```
public String rInString(String theDisplay) {
    String a = theDisplay;
    String b = word;
    String c = Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement);
    if(matchWholeWord != null && matchWholeWord){
        b = "([^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Lower}\\p{Space}])" + b + 
            "([^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Lower}\\p{Space}])";
        a = " " + a + " ";
        c = "$1" + c + "$2";
    }
    return message.replaceAll("(?i:" + b + " )", c).trim();
}

public String rInString(String theDisplay, String theB, String replace) {
    String c = Matcher.quoteReplacement(replace);
    String a = theDisplay;
    String b = theB;
    if (matchWholeWord != null && matchWholeWord) {
        b = "([^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Space}])" + b + "([^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Space}])";
        a = " " + a + " ";
        c = "$1" + c + "$2";
    }

    return message.replaceAll("(?i:" + b + ")", c).trim();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can put some context on these functions/variables? I'm trying to follow the flow of the code but its pretty obfuscated, I don't know what 'a', 'b', 'theB', 'c', 'theDisplay', 'matchWholeWord' is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the help, I figured out what it was.  I needed to make sure the RegEx was Alnum and not Alpha.

Comment: I'm changing my handle to iwantabananbleep

Comment: Will it complain if I come from `Scunthorpe`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that one letter (a) was being blocked because $$ are the terminus in the RegEx statement.  This meant that the a was being counted as a bad element.  Each $ needed to be escaped in the SQL statement.